# Sending Linq expressions over WCF

Tags: wcf, linq, serialization

I want to be able to send linq queries over wcf just like in ria services and wcf data services, but I do not want to use either of them.
Are there any codeplex project or similar which could help me with this problem.
Or are there easey to extract that code from ria with reflector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a way to [de]serialize the expression trees. I would look at  either http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization or MetaLinq: http://metalinq.codeplex.com/ to help with this.